# sequence diagram request portlet

Tags: java, client-server, portlet, sequence-diagram, jsr286

In detail, I would like to know if it is the right representation between the portal and the portal container.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

That depends on your portal. The action phase comes first. Afterwards the portal may start rendering any portlet. The portlets can even be rendered parallely.

Comment: Thanks for replay. Yes, this I konw, wondering if it's just the dialogue between Portal and PortletContainer.